# How to make an App Engine Connected Android Project?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, eclipse-plugin

I used [this Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appengine_connected_android) to find out about App Engine Connected Android Projects. On [this page](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_create_project) Google explains how to make such a project, however, the menu item that should exist in Eclipse doesn't.

I installed all the prerequisites, I have a recognized and working Android, App Engine and GWT SDK installed, and I installed most of the Google Eclipse plugins. (I only skipped those I was sure of they would not be needed for this.)

So for some reason, that option was removed from the plugin. But the documentation does still exist. Is there an alternative way to easily achieve the same? I want to do exactly that what that type of projects was intended for: make a App Engine-backed Web App and corresponding Android App through C2DM.

Am I missing some Eclipse plugin or is this type of projects really removed? Anyone that knows how to set up the same?

(If not, is it possible to setup an Android and App Engine project as one Eclipse project? Note that this is not my main question.)

Comment: This comprehensive tutorial should help you: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html  I am not much in touch with C2DM lately, so not aware what they have changed in last 1 year or so

Comment: That's just info on C2DM. I'm looking for a method to create an Eclipse project that contains an App Engine project as well as an Android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers on this question suggest that the menu item is absent because of the deprecation of the C2DM platform to make place for GCM.

Although Google states it planned to add the menu item back at the end of July, it seems they didn't do so yet now in September.